# Using SPServices to disable a field if a user IS NOT a member of a specified SharePoint group

Tags: sharepoint-2010, spservices

Working in SharePoint 2010 Foundation, I'm trying to disable a field on a custom editform.aspx for users who are not members of a specific group.

So, if current user is not a member of the group "Change Control - Admins", disable the CCID field.

I found what seemed to be the solution in the SPServices codeplex discussion area, but it doesn't work as expected.  Not sure what I'm missing here.

It does disable the correct field, but does not matter if current user is in the specified group or not.

If i change this:

if($(xData.responseXML).find("Group[Name='Change Control - Admins']").length != 1)

to this:

if($(xData.responseXML).find("Group[Name='Change Control - Admins']").length == 1)

...then the field does not get disabled.  However, it again doesn't matter if the current user is in the specified group or not.

Any help would be much appreciated.

Here's my code:

```
<script language="javascript" type="text/javascript" src="/CodeLibrary/jquery-1.7.2.min.js"></script>
<script language="javascript" type="text/javascript" src="/CodeLibrary/jquery.SPServices-0.7.2.min.ssl.js"></script>
<script language="javascript" type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function() {
var groupName;

 $().SPServices({  
      operation: "GetGroupCollectionFromUser",  
      userLoginName: $().SPServices.SPGetCurrentUser(),  
      async: false,  
      completefunc: function(xData, Status) { 
        //if current user is not a member of this group...  
        if($(xData.responseXML).find("Group[Name='Change Control - Admins']").length != 1)  
        {  
              //...disable the following fields
              $("input[Title='CCID']").prop("disabled", "disabled");
              }  
      }  
    });  
});

function PreSaveAction() {
    $("input[Title='CCID']").removeProp("disabled");
    return true;
}
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm doing something very similar. In my case I'm checking the group membership for groups beginning with "GCP" and extracting some text from the matching groups. What has been really useful is logging to the Firefox console using `console.log()`. The Firefox console allows you to drill down into objects that you log to the console - something not provided by IE (this logging code should not be included in release code, particularly because it can fail in IE). The console is available from the *Web Developer* menu in Firefox.

```
 $(document).ready(function() {
   $().SPServices({
     operation: "GetGroupCollectionFromUser",
     userLoginName: $().SPServices.SPGetCurrentUser(),
     async: false,
     completefunc: function(xData, Status) {
        console.log(xData.responseXML);
        var $groups = $(xData.responseXML).find("Group[Name^='GCP']");
        console.log("$groups.length:" + $groups.length);
        if ($groups.length) console.log($groups.get(0).outerHTML);
        var re = /GCP ((?:[^ ]*)(?:(?! Managers) [^ *]*)*) Managers/i;
        var org = "";
        $groups.each(function(index, elt){
            var name = $(this).attr("Name");
            var matches = re.exec(name);
            if (matches){
                org = matches[1];
                return false;
            }
        });
        setOrg(org);
     }
   });
});
```